# Can text2vec and topicmodels generate similar topics with suitable parameter settings for LDA?

Tags: r, lda, topicmodels, text2vec

I was wondering how results of different packages, hence, algorithms, differ and if parameters could be set in a way to produce similar topics. I had a look at the packages `text2vec` and `topicmodels` in particular.

I used below code to compare 10 topics (see code section for terms) generated with these packages. I could not manage to generate sets of topics with similar meaning. E.g. topic 10 from `text2vec` has something to do with "police", none of the topics produced by `topicmodels` refers to "police" or similar terms. Further, I could not identify a pendant of topic 5 produced by `topicmodels` that has something to do with "life-love-familiy-war" in the topics produced by `text2vec`.

I am a beginner with LDA, hence, my understanding may sound naive for experienced programmers. However, intuitively, one would asssume that it should be possible to produce sets of topics with similar meaning to prove validity/robustness of results. Of course, not necessarily the exact same set of terms, but termlists addressing similar topics.

Maybe the issue is simply that my human interpretation of these termlists is not good enough to capture similarities, but maybe there are some parameters that might increase similarity for human interpretation. Can someone guide me on how to set  parameters to achieve this or otherwise provide explanations or hint on suitable resources to improve my understanding of the matter?

Here some issues that might be relevant:

- I know that `text2vec` does not use standard Gibbs sampling but [WarpLDA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.08628), which already is a difference in the algorithm to `topcimodels`. If my understanding is correct, the priors `alpha` and `delta` used in `topicmodels` are set as `doc_topic_prior` and `topic_word_prior` in `text2vec` respectively.
- Furthermore, in postprocessing, text2vec allows the adaption of `lambda` for sorting terms of topics based on their frequency. I have not yet understood, how terms are sorted in `topicmodels` - comparable to setting `lambda=1`?. (I have tried different lambdas between 0 to 1 without getting similar topics)
- Another issue is that is seems difficult to produce a fully reproducible example even when setting `seed` [(see, e.g., this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742181/different-results-of-lda-using-rtopicmodels?noredirect=1&lq=1). This is not directly my question but might make it more difficult to respond.

Sorry for the lenghty question and thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

**Update2:** I have moved the content of my first update into an answer that is based on a more complete analysis.

**Update:** Following the helpful comment of `text2vec` package creator [Dmitriy Selivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069256/dmitriy-selivanov), I can confirm that setting `lambda=1` increases the similarity of topics betweeen the termlists produced by the two packages.

Furthermore, I had a closer look at the differences between termlists produced by both packages via a quick check of `length(setdiff())` and `length(intersect())` across topics (see in below code). This rough check shows  that `text2vec` discards several terms per topic - probably by a threshold of probability for the individual topics? `topicmodels` keeps all terms for all topics. This explains part of the differences in meanings that can be derived (by a human) from the termlists.

As mentioned above already, generating a reproducible example seems difficult, so I have not adapted all data examples in below code. Since run time is short, anybody can check on his/her own system.

```
    library(text2vec)
    library(topicmodels)
    library(slam) #to convert dtm to simple triplet matrix for topicmodels

    ntopics <- 10
    alphaprior <- 0.1
    deltaprior <- 0.001
    niter <- 1000
    convtol <- 0.001
    set.seed(0) #for text2vec
    seedpar <- 0 #for topicmodels

    #Generate document term matrix with text2vec    
    tokens = movie_review$review[1:1000] %>% 
             tolower %>% 
             word_tokenizer

    it = itoken(tokens, ids = movie_review$id[1:1000], progressbar = FALSE)

    vocab = create_vocabulary(it) %>%
            prune_vocabulary(term_count_min = 10, doc_proportion_max = 0.2)

    vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vocab)

    dtm = create_dtm(it, vectorizer, type = "dgTMatrix")


    #LDA model with text2vec
    lda_model = text2vec::LDA$new(n_topics = ntopics
                                  ,doc_topic_prior = alphaprior
                                  ,topic_word_prior = deltaprior
                                  )

    doc_topic_distr = lda_model$fit_transform(x =  dtm
                                              ,n_iter = niter
                                              ,convergence_tol = convtol
                                              ,n_check_convergence = 25
                                              ,progressbar = FALSE
                                              )    


    #LDA model with topicmodels
    ldatopicmodels <- LDA(as.simple_triplet_matrix(dtm), k = ntopics, method = "Gibbs",
                             LDA_Gibbscontrol = list(burnin = 100
                                                     ,delta = deltaprior
                                                     ,alpha = alphaprior
                                                     ,iter = niter
                                                     ,keep = 50
                                                     ,tol = convtol
                                                     ,seed = seedpar
                                                     ,initialize = "seeded"
                             )
    )

    #show top 15 words
    lda_model$get_top_words(n = 10, topic_number = c(1:10), lambda = 0.3)
    #       [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]         [,6]         [,7]         [,8]      [,9]         [,10]       
    # [1,] "finally"   "men"       "know"      "video"    "10"         "king"       "five"       "our"     "child"      "cop"       
    # [2,] "re"        "always"    "ve"        "1"        "doesn"      "match"      "atmosphere" "husband" "later"      "themselves"
    # [3,] "three"     "lost"      "got"       "head"     "zombie"     "lee"        "mr"         "comedy"  "parents"    "mary"      
    # [4,] "m"         "team"      "say"       "girls"    "message"    "song"       "de"         "seem"    "sexual"     "average"   
    # [5,] "gay"       "here"      "d"         "camera"   "start"      "musical"    "may"        "man"     "murder"     "scenes"    
    # [6,] "kids"      "within"    "funny"     "kill"     "3"          "four"       "especially" "problem" "tale"       "police"    
    # [7,] "sort"      "score"     "want"      "stupid"   "zombies"    "dance"      "quality"    "friends" "television" "appears"   
    # [8,] "few"       "thriller"  "movies"    "talking"  "movies"     "action"     "public"     "given"   "okay"       "trying"    
    # [9,] "bit"       "surprise"  "let"       "hard"     "ask"        "fun"        "events"     "crime"   "cover"      "waiting"   
   # [10,] "hot"       "own"       "thinking"  "horrible" "won"        "tony"       "u"          "special" "stan"       "lewis"     
   # [11,] "die"       "political" "nice"      "stay"     "open"       "twist"      "kelly"      "through" "uses"       "imdb"      
   # [12,] "credits"   "success"   "never"     "back"     "davis"      "killer"     "novel"      "world"   "order"      "candy"     
   # [13,] "two"       "does"      "bunch"     "didn"     "completely" "ending"     "copy"       "show"    "strange"    "name"      
   # [14,] "otherwise" "beauty"    "hilarious" "room"     "love"       "dancing"    "japanese"   "new"     "female"     "low"       
   # [15,] "need"      "brilliant" "lot"       "minutes"  "away"       "convincing" "far"        "mostly"  "girl"       "killing"       

    terms(ldatopicmodels, 10)
    #      Topic 1     Topic 2   Topic 3       Topic 4   Topic 5    Topic 6       Topic 7     Topic 8      Topic 9    Topic 10
    # [1,] "show"     "where"   "horror"       "did"     "life"    "such"      "m"         "films"       "man"      "seen"       
    # [2,] "years"    "minutes" "pretty"       "10"      "young"   "character" "something" "music"       "new"      "movies"     
    # [3,] "old"      "gets"    "best"         "now"     "through" "while"     "re"        "actors"      "two"      "plot"       
    # [4,] "every"    "guy"     "ending"       "why"     "love"    "those"     "going"     "role"        "though"   "better"     
    # [5,] "series"   "another" "bit"          "saw"     "woman"   "does"      "things"    "performance" "big"      "worst"          
    # [6,] "funny"    "around"  "quite"        "didn"    "us"      "seems"     "want"      "between"     "back"     "interesting"
    # [7,] "comedy"   "nothing" "little"       "say"     "real"    "book"      "thing"     "love"        "action"   "your"       
    # [8,] "again"    "down"    "actually"     "thought" "our"     "may"       "know"      "play"        "shot"     "money"      
    # [9,] "tv"       "take"    "house"        "still"   "war"     "work"      "ve"        "line"        "together" "hard"       
    # [10,] "watching" "these"   "however"      "end"     "father"  "far"       "here"      "actor"       "against"  "poor"       
    # [11,] "cast"     "fun"     "cast"         "got"     "find"    "scenes"    "doesn"     "star"        "title"    "least"      
    # [12,] "long"     "night"   "entertaining" "2"       "human"   "both"      "look"      "never"       "go"       "say"        
    # [13,] "through"  "scene"   "must"         "am"      "shows"   "yet"       "isn"       "played"      "city"     "director"   
    # [14,] "once"     "back"    "each"         "done"    "family"  "audience"  "anything"  "hollywood"   "came"     "probably"   
    # [15,] "watched"  "dead"    "makes"        "3"       "mother"  "almost"    "enough"    "always"      "match"    "video" 

#UPDATE

#number of terms in each model is the same
length(ldatopicmodels@terms)
# [1] 2170
nrow(vocab)
# [1] 2170

#number of NA entries for termlist of first topic differs
sum(is.na(
          lda_model$get_top_words(n = nrow(vocab), topic_number = c(1:10), lambda = 1)[,1]
         )
    )
#[1] 1778

sum(is.na(
          terms(ldatopicmodels, length(ldatopicmodels@terms))
         )
   )
#[1] 0


#function to check number of terms that differ between two sets of topic collections (excluding NAs)
lengthsetdiff <- function(x, y) {

  apply(x, 2, function(i) {

    apply(y, 2, function(j) {

      length(setdiff(i[!is.na(i)],j[!is.na(j)]))
    })

  })

}


#apply the check
termstopicmodels <- terms(ldatopicmodels,length(ldatopicmodels@terms))
termstext2vec <- lda_model$get_top_words(n = nrow(vocab), topic_number = c(1:10), lambda = 1)


lengthsetdiff(termstopicmodels,
          termstopicmodels)
# Topic 1 Topic 2 Topic 3 Topic 4 Topic 5 Topic 6 Topic 7 Topic 8 Topic 9 Topic 10
# Topic 1        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 2        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 3        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 4        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 5        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 6        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 7        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 8        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 9        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 10       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0

lengthsetdiff(termstext2vec,
              termstext2vec)
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0  340  318  335  292  309  320  355  294   322
# [2,]  355    0  321  343  292  319  311  346  302   339
# [3,]  350  338    0  316  286  309  311  358  318   322
# [4,]  346  339  295    0  297  310  301  335  309   332
# [5,]  345  330  307  339    0  310  310  354  309   333
# [6,]  350  345  318  340  298    0  311  342  308   325
# [7,]  366  342  325  336  303  316    0  364  311   325
# [8,]  355  331  326  324  301  301  318    0  311   335
# [9,]  336  329  328  340  298  309  307  353    0   314
# [10,]  342  344  310  341  300  304  299  355  292     0

lengthsetdiff(termstopicmodels,
              termstext2vec)
# Topic 1 Topic 2 Topic 3 Topic 4 Topic 5 Topic 6 Topic 7 Topic 8 Topic 9 Topic 10
# [1,]    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778     1778
# [2,]    1793    1793    1793    1793    1793    1793    1793    1793    1793     1793
# [3,]    1810    1810    1810    1810    1810    1810    1810    1810    1810     1810
# [4,]    1789    1789    1789    1789    1789    1789    1789    1789    1789     1789
# [5,]    1831    1831    1831    1831    1831    1831    1831    1831    1831     1831
# [6,]    1819    1819    1819    1819    1819    1819    1819    1819    1819     1819
# [7,]    1824    1824    1824    1824    1824    1824    1824    1824    1824     1824
# [8,]    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778    1778     1778
# [9,]    1820    1820    1820    1820    1820    1820    1820    1820    1820     1820
# [10,]    1798    1798    1798    1798    1798    1798    1798    1798    1798     1798

lengthsetdiff(termstext2vec,
              termstopicmodels)
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# Topic 1     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 2     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 3     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 4     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 5     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 6     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 7     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 8     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 9     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0

#also the intersection can be checked between the two sets
lengthintersect <- function(x, y) {

  apply(x, 2, function(i) {

    apply(y, 2, function(j) {

      length(intersect(i[!is.na(i)], j[!is.na(j)]))
    })

  })

}

lengthintersect(termstopicmodels,
                termstext2vec)

# Topic 1 Topic 2 Topic 3 Topic 4 Topic 5 Topic 6 Topic 7 Topic 8 Topic 9 Topic 10
# [1,]     392     392     392     392     392     392     392     392     392      392
# [2,]     377     377     377     377     377     377     377     377     377      377
# [3,]     360     360     360     360     360     360     360     360     360      360
# [4,]     381     381     381     381     381     381     381     381     381      381
# [5,]     339     339     339     339     339     339     339     339     339      339
# [6,]     351     351     351     351     351     351     351     351     351      351
# [7,]     346     346     346     346     346     346     346     346     346      346
# [8,]     392     392     392     392     392     392     392     392     392      392
# [9,]     350     350     350     350     350     350     350     350     350      350
# [10,]     372     372     372     372     372     372     372     372     372      372
```

Comment: I think `lambda = 1` corresponds to how `topicmodels` sorts terms.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful response. I have updated my question and introduced some findings concerning differences of output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having updated my question with some comparison results, I was still interested more in detail. Therefore, I have run lda models on the complete `movie_review` data set included in `text2vec` (5000 docs). To produce half-way realistic results, I have also introduced some gentle pre-processing and stopword removal. (Sorry for the long code example below)

My conclusion is that some of the "good" topics (from a subjective standpoint) produced by the two packages are comparable to a certain extent (especially the last three topics in below example are not really good and were difficult to compare). However, looking at similar topics between the two packages, produced different (subjective) associations for each topic. Hence, the standard `Gibbs` sampling and the `WarpLDA` algorithm seem to capture similar topical areas for the given data, but with different "moods" expressed in the topics.

I would see the main reason for the differences in the fact that the `WarpLDA` algorithm seems to discard terms and introduce `NA` values in the `beta` matrix (term-topic-distribution). See below example for this. Hence, its faster convergence seems to be achieved by sacrificing completeness.

I do not want to judge which topics are subjectively "better" and leave this to your own judgement.

One important limitation of this analysis is, that I have not (yet) checked the results for an optimal number of topics, I only used `k=10`. Hence, comparability of the topics might increase for an optimal `k`, in any case the quality will improve and thereby maybe the "mood". (The optimal `k` might again differ between the algorithms depending on the measure used to find `k`.)

```
library(text2vec)
library(topicmodels)
library(slam) #to convert dtm to simple triplet matrix for topicmodels
library(LDAvis)
library(tm) #for stopwords only

ntopics <- 10
alphaprior <- 0.1
deltaprior <- 0.001
niter <- 1000
convtol <- 0.001
set.seed(0) #for text2vec
seedpar <- 0 #for topicmodels

docs <- movie_review$review

preproc_fun <- function(x) {
  tolower(x) %>% 
  { gsub("[\\W]+", " ", ., perl=T) } %>% 
  { gsub("[\\d]+", " ", ., perl=T) } %>% 
  { gsub(paste0("(?<=\\b)(\\w{1,", 2, "})(?=\\b)"), "", ., perl=T) } %>% 
  { gsub("\\s+", " ", . , perl=T) } %>% 
  { gsub("^\\s|\\s$", "", ., perl=T) } %>% 
  return()
}

#Generate document term matrix with text2vec    
tokens = docs %>% 
  preproc_fun %>% 
  word_tokenizer

it = itoken(tokens, ids = movie_review$id, progressbar = FALSE)

vocab = create_vocabulary(it, stopwords = tm::stopwords()) %>%
  prune_vocabulary(term_count_min = 10, doc_proportion_max = 0.2)

vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vocab)

dtm = create_dtm(it, vectorizer, type = "dgTMatrix")
dim(dtm)
# [1] 5000 7407

#LDA model with text2vec
ldatext2vec = text2vec::LDA$new(n_topics = ntopics
                              ,doc_topic_prior = alphaprior
                              ,topic_word_prior = deltaprior
)

doc_topic_distr = ldatext2vec$fit_transform(x =  dtm
                                          ,n_iter = niter
                                          ,convergence_tol = convtol
                                          ,n_check_convergence = 25
                                          ,progressbar = FALSE
)    


control_Gibbs_topicmodels <- list(
                             alpha = alphaprior
                            ,delta = deltaprior
                            ,iter = niter
                            ,burnin = 100
                            ,keep = 50
                            ,nstart = 1
                            ,best = TRUE
                            ,seed = seedpar
                            )

#LDA model with topicmodels
ldatopicmodels <- LDA(as.simple_triplet_matrix(dtm)
                      ,k = ntopics
                      ,method = "Gibbs"
                      ,control = control_Gibbs_topicmodels 
                       )


#I have ordered the topics manually after printing top 15 terms and put similar (at least from my subjective standpoint) topics at the beginning
topicsterms_ldatopicmodels <- terms(ldatopicmodels,length(ldatopicmodels@terms))[,c(6,8,10,3,5,9,7,4,1,2)]
topicsterms_ldatext2vec <- ldatext2vec$get_top_words(n = nrow(vocab), topic_number = c(1:10), lambda = 1)[, c(9,6,4,10,5,3,7,2,8,1)]

#show top 15 words
topicsterms_ldatext2vec[1:15,]
#       [,1]       [,2]          [,3]          [,4]       [,5]       [,6]        [,7]    [,8]       [,9]        [,10]    
# [1,] "show"     "performance" "films"       "war"      "horror"   "say"       "man"   "love"     "know"      "man"    
# [2,] "series"   "role"        "director"    "american" "killer"   "better"    "back"  "life"     "say"       "woman"  
# [3,] "funny"    "films"       "scenes"      "book"     "doesn"    "nothing"   "last"  "big"      "life"      "life"   
# [4,] "still"    "music"       "audience"    "may"      "little"   "watching"  "match" "real"     "didn"      "police" 
# [5,] "original" "love"        "though"      "world"    "isn"      "know"      "big"   "women"    "going"     "father" 
# [6,] "years"    "cast"        "may"         "young"    "guy"      "worst"     "men"   "job"      "now"       "world"  
# [7,] "version"  "john"        "quite"       "family"   "actually" "didn"      "takes" "black"    "something" "black"  
# [8,] "episode"  "play"        "real"        "mother"   "gets"     "something" "woman" "new"      "things"    "wife"   
# [9,] "now"      "man"         "seems"       "true"     "dead"     "actors"    "take"  "money"    "back"      "goes"   
# [10,] "dvd"      "played"      "work"        "years"    "look"     "minutes"   "young" "work"     "saw"       "new"    
# [11,] "saw"      "actor"       "scene"       "novel"    "house"    "films"     "life"  "game"     "family"    "without"
# [12,] "old"      "excellent"   "actors"      "however"  "looks"    "least"     "city"  "world"    "love"      "around" 
# [13,] "watching" "young"       "interesting" "small"    "poor"     "script"    "town"  "still"    "thought"   "scene"  
# [14,] "watched"  "perfect"     "rather"      "quite"    "pretty"   "budget"    "dance" "comedy"   "got"       "shot"   
# [15,] "better"   "high"        "yet"         "history"  "stupid"   "lot"       "rock"  "american" "thing"     "another"

topicsterms_ldatopicmodels[1:15,]
#       Topic 6   Topic 8        Topic 10    Topic 3       Topic 5  Topic 9    Topic 7   Topic 4    Topic 1  Topic 2    
# [1,] "show"    "performance"  "films"     "war"         "horror" "funny"    "man"     "love"     "life"   "little"   
# [2,] "years"   "role"         "director"  "american"    "house"  "better"   "wife"    "book"     "love"   "music"    
# [3,] "series"  "cast"         "something" "documentary" "scene"  "say"      "gets"    "films"    "world"  "action"   
# [4,] "now"     "actor"        "enough"    "part"        "killer" "know"     "father"  "version"  "young"  "fun"      
# [5,] "episode" "play"         "doesn"     "world"       "sex"    "watching" "back"    "still"    "family" "big"      
# [6,] "old"     "performances" "nothing"   "history"     "scenes" "thing"    "goes"    "original" "real"   "rock"     
# [7,] "back"    "comedy"       "actually"  "america"     "gore"   "pretty"   "new"     "quite"    "may"    "king"     
# [8,] "love"    "played"       "things"    "new"         "blood"  "guy"      "woman"   "music"    "man"    "animation"
# [9,] "saw"     "director"     "seems"     "hollywood"   "around" "didn"     "later"   "years"    "work"   "films"    
# [10,] "shows"   "job"          "know"      "japanese"    "little" "got"      "home"    "scenes"   "little" "black"    
# [11,] "new"     "john"         "without"   "white"       "woman"  "worst"    "money"   "old"      "lives"  "song"     
# [12,] "family"  "actors"       "real"      "shot"        "night"  "thought"  "son"     "scene"    "mother" "pretty"   
# [13,] "dvd"     "star"         "far"       "despite"     "dead"   "wasn"     "police"  "better"   "men"    "quite"    
# [14,] "still"   "excellent"    "might"     "still"       "zombie" "minutes"  "husband" "bit"      "find"   "musical"  
# [15,] "know"    "work"         "fact"      "early"       "scary"  "stupid"   "town"    "times"    "women"  "effects" 

#number of total terms for each model is the same
#however, the ldatext2vec from text2vec has NA values
length(ldatopicmodels@terms)
# [1] 7407
length(ldatopicmodels@terms[ !is.na(ldatopicmodels@terms)])
# [1] 7407

terms_ldatext2vec <- unique(as.character(topicsterms_ldatext2vec))
length(terms_ldatext2vec)
# [1] 7408
length(terms_ldatext2vec[!is.na(terms_ldatext2vec)])
# [1] 7407

#number of NA entries in topic/termlists of text2vec ldatext2vec
dim(topicsterms_ldatext2vec)
#[1] 7407   10
sum(is.na(topicsterms_ldatext2vec))
# [1] 60368
#share of NA values
sum(is.na(topicsterms_ldatext2vec))/(dim(topicsterms_ldatext2vec)[1]*dim(topicsterms_ldatext2vec)[2])
#[1] 0.8150128

#no NA values in ldatopicmodels
sum(is.na(terms(ldatopicmodels, length(ldatopicmodels@terms))))
#[1] 0

#function to check number of terms that differ between two sets of topic collections (excluding NAs)
lengthsetdiff <- function(x, y) {
  apply(x, 2, function(i) {
    apply(y, 2, function(j) {
      length(setdiff(i[!is.na(i)],j[!is.na(j)]))
    })
  })
}

#also the intersection can be checked between the two sets
lengthintersect <- function(x, y) {
  apply(x, 2, function(i) {
    apply(y, 2, function(j) {
      length(intersect(i[!is.na(i)], j[!is.na(j)]))
    })
  })
}

#since especially the top words are of interest, we first check the intersection of top 20 words
#please note that the order of the topics, especially the last 3 is subjective
lengthintersect(topicsterms_ldatopicmodels[1:20,],
                topicsterms_ldatext2vec[1:20,])
#          Topic 6 Topic 8 Topic 10 Topic 3 Topic 5 Topic 9 Topic 7 Topic 4 Topic 1 Topic 2
# [1,]      13       1        0       2       0       3       1       7       1       2
# [2,]       1       9        1       0       0       0       2       4       5       4
# [3,]       0       4        8       0       2       0       0       4       3       2
# [4,]       3       0        0       5       2       0       1       5       6       2
# [5,]       1       0        3       0       7       7       1       1       1       2
# [6,]       2       3        6       0       0      10       0       3       0       1
# [7,]       4       2        1       2       1       0       8       1       4       3
# [8,]       3       4        2       5       1       1       2       3       8       5
# [9,]      10       0        4       0       0       8       1       3       3       1
# [10,]      1       0        1       3       3       0       7       1       5       2



#apply the check with the topics ordered as shown above for the top 15 words

#all words are appear in each topic
lengthsetdiff(topicsterms_ldatopicmodels,
              topicsterms_ldatopicmodels)
#             Topic 1 Topic 2 Topic 3 Topic 4 Topic 5 Topic 6 Topic 7 Topic 8 Topic 9 Topic 10
# Topic 1        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 2        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 3        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 4        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 5        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 6        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 7        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 8        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 9        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0
# Topic 10       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0

#not all words appear in each topic
lengthsetdiff(topicsterms_ldatext2vec ,
              topicsterms_ldatext2vec )
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0 1188 1216 1241 1086 1055 1196 1131 1126  1272
# [2,] 1029    0 1203 1223 1139 1073 1188 1140 1188  1260
# [3,] 1032 1178    0 1224 1084 1024 1186 1122 1164  1238
# [4,] 1075 1216 1242    0 1175 1139 1202 1152 1207  1271
# [5,] 1011 1223 1193 1266    0 1082 1170 1170 1160  1214
# [6,]  993 1170 1146 1243 1095    0 1178 1119 1092  1206
# [7,] 1078 1229 1252 1250 1127 1122    0 1200 1195  1227
# [8,] 1030 1198 1205 1217 1144 1080 1217    0 1171  1211
# [9,]  966 1187 1188 1213 1075  994 1153 1112    0  1198
# [10,] 1095 1242 1245 1260 1112 1091 1168 1135 1181     0

#difference of terms in topics per topic between the two models
lengthsetdiff(topicsterms_ldatopicmodels,
              topicsterms_ldatext2vec)
#         Topic 6 Topic 8 Topic 10 Topic 3 Topic 5 Topic 9 Topic 7 Topic 4 Topic 1 Topic 2
# [1,]    6157    6157     6157    6157    6157    6157    6157    6157    6157    6157
# [2,]    5998    5998     5998    5998    5998    5998    5998    5998    5998    5998
# [3,]    5973    5973     5973    5973    5973    5973    5973    5973    5973    5973
# [4,]    5991    5991     5991    5991    5991    5991    5991    5991    5991    5991
# [5,]    6082    6082     6082    6082    6082    6082    6082    6082    6082    6082
# [6,]    6095    6095     6095    6095    6095    6095    6095    6095    6095    6095
# [7,]    6039    6039     6039    6039    6039    6039    6039    6039    6039    6039
# [8,]    6056    6056     6056    6056    6056    6056    6056    6056    6056    6056
# [9,]    5997    5997     5997    5997    5997    5997    5997    5997    5997    5997
# [10,]    5980    5980     5980    5980    5980    5980    5980    5980    5980    5980

lengthsetdiff(topicsterms_ldatext2vec,
              topicsterms_ldatopicmodels)
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# Topic 6     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 8     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 3     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 5     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 9     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 7     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 4     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 1     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# Topic 2     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```