# How to reproduce topic modelling results with LDA package in R

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I am using the lda package in R to perform Latent Dirichlet Allocation modelling. However, each time I run the program I get a different output.

Using set.seed() doesn't seem to help [like with the topicmodels package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623309/how-to-reproduce-exact-results-with-lda-function-in-rs-topicmodels-package).

Assuming an identical input, is there a way to ensure that identical topics are found on subsequent executions of the code?

I execute the function as follows:

```
set.seed(11)
fit1 <- lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler(documents = documents, K = topics, vocab = vocab,
                               num.iterations = iterations, alpha = alpha,
                               eta = eta, initial = NULL, burnin = 500,
                               compute.log.likelihood = TRUE)
```

Comment: have u tried to set 'initial' in the argument

Comment: I have, but it still generates different topics every time